# Convert Wordpress to static website by using the pages generated by the caching plugin?

Tags: cache, static-website

Since the caching is already making HTML pages, I was wondering if those pages can be used as a static version of the site.
Example:

- Have a private WordPress installation with caching plugin
- A solution to auto-export the cached HTML pages to public website

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no general method of doing this that works for all plugins.** And no generic WordPress steps to take or officially supported paths.

Each plugin requires a unique answer and solution that is very specific to that plugin. Some plugins may not support this, while others already depend on doing this. You would need to enquire with the specific plugin vendor via their support routes/documentation, or ask other users.